# Make a Square Over an Image?

Tags: css, sass

I want to make a pink square over an image like in the picture below.

[image: Square over image]

**Update:** The result:

[image: My square over image]

Here's my code:

```css
.pink-square {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -100px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    background-color: #FF3366;
}

.square-content {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="square-content">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
        <div class="pink-square">
            <h1>"</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```css
//- Reset CSS
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** To see the rest of the code, please see it here => https://github.com/cate-k/demo-website-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this a couple of days ago but forgot to post it here.

This is the code that works for me:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.square-over-image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 40rem;
}

.text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: #FF3366;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 30rem;
}

.rachel-ashburn-picture {
    background-image: url(asset/image/rachel-ashburn.jpg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    left: 0;
    top: 7vh;
    margin-left: 4rem;
    position: relative;
}

.rachel-name {
    padding: 2rem
}

.rachel-title {
    margin-left: 23.4rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    left: 0.5vw;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.rachel-ashburn {
    position: unset;
    line-height: 0.2rem;

    .rachel-ashburn-picture {
        background-image: url(asset/image/rachel-ashburn.jpg);
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-position: center top;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-left: 3.5rem;
        top: 3rem;
    }
    
    .rachel-name {
        left: 8.5vw;
        top: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .rachel-title {
        left: 3.5vw;
        top: -1rem;
    }
}
```

```html
    .container
        img.square-over-image(src="/asset/image/women-talking.jpg", alt="Friends")
        .text-block
            h4 ”
            p Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.
                .rachel-ashburn
                    .rachel-ashburn-picture
                    span.rachel-name #[h5 Rachel Ashburn]
                    span.rachel-title #[p Web Designer]
```

Thanks for all your help, everyone!

[image: The result I wanted]

Answer (score 1):

I used the image as the basis and positioned the pink square absolutely. Further documentation in the CSS code.

```css
.pink-square {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: -100px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  background-color: pink;
}

.square-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px; /* Needed to make .pink-square visible completely */
  margin-left: 50px; /* Needed to make .pink-square visible completely */
}
```

```html
<div class="square-content">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
  <div class="pink-square">
    <h1>"</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've got a different result than yours, is there something wrong with my code? (I've updated my question so you can see the new code.)

Comment: @CateK.except for the background color, I can't see any difference. You may have additional setting in your live site that are causing the differences. Do you have a URL to look at?

Comment: Not yet. Do you think the screen size might be the problem?

Comment: @CateK. No, not the screen size. What it looks like, is that you have a parent container that has a width with a calculated value more than 100%. You can add width: 100vw to .square-content just to validate if the result is according to expectations. This would be a temporary fix however,

Comment: Oh, okay. I've had this in the code:

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-box: box-sizing;
}

Comment: @CateK.I suggest you put **all** the HTML and CSS code here so we can figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Sure! I'll do that in a few seconds. Except would you like me to paste the link to the GitHub repo instead?

Comment: Okay, I've added the link and a bit more of what I think might be part of the problem.

Comment: @CateK. it's a start. Any link available that actually contains the image and the square as included in the update above?

Comment: in find files, type src/_component/layout. It's in the layout.scss file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, what I mean is to see the boxes on a page

Answer (score 1):

Create a container (a div) that will contain both the image and the box. Then use absolute positioning to set the image to be flush against the right and bottom of the container, and to set the box to be flush against the top and left of the container. If you order it properly, the box should be on top of the image, but use could use z-index to make sure that it's on top.

[Here's a simple example on codepen](https://codepen.io/stephen-brown-bourne/pen/wYebPW)

```css
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 background: #ccc;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.box {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #FF3366;
}
.image {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <h2>Put Content Here</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="image">
  <img src="https://gradientjoy.com/600x300?id=24" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen! I'll look into this after I try Gerard's answer. :)